# gwt-unit cache does not exist

Tags: svn

I am facing this error when i try to commit my SVN .

```
svn: 'C:\Users\wageeha junaid\workspace\Copy of HOLS\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache- 00000132A65F0D8B' does not exist
```

Comment: Maybe just `C:\Users\wageeha junaid\workspace\Copy of HOLS\gwt-unitCache\gwt-unitCache- 00000132A65F0D8B` happens not to exist. Did you check out your local file system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should not commit the unitCache to the versioning system. use [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) for that purpose.

Comment: What exactly is in the gwt-unitCache directory? It looks like binaries.

Comment: _Persistent Unit Cache: GWT Compiler and Development mode now cache compilation artifacts between runs. This results in faster startup time for iterative development._

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix if you are using Eclipse: Right click on the gwt-unitCache folder and press Refresh. The problem is that you need to update the folder from the package explorer before you commit.